# Xamarin Forms Forcing Page Specific Orientation on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a couple of pages in my XF app that require being portrait or landscape depending on the content it's displaying. On Android, this is no problem and was also never a problem on iOS until iOS 16 was released.

iOS 16 apparently removed the ability to use UIDevice UIInterfaceOrientation method seen below which was in my AppDelegate.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "SetLandscapeModeOff", sender =>
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
            });
```

This worked great and I could simply call the code below in the OnAppearing method on the page I was trying to load in a specific orientation.

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SetLandscapeModeOff");
```

I've seen 1 or 2 posts on here talking about new methods (and a lot on pre iOS 16 methods) but none of them are complete enough for someone of my skill level to understand how to implement them. I don't have any starting point other than what is posted above.

***EDIT***

I've attempted the below solution based on the reply.

**Interface:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp
{
    public interface InterfaceOrientationService
    {
        void SetLandscape();
        void SetPortrait();
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyApp.iOS.InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS))]

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS : InterfaceOrientationService
    {
        public InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS() { }

        public void SetLandscape()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))
            {
                var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);

                if (windowScene != null)
                {
                    var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
                    if (nav != null)
                    {
                        nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
                        windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate(
                            new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                            error => { }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
            }
        }
        public void SetPortrait()
        {

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))
            {
                var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);
                if (windowScene != null)
                {
                    var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
                    if (nav != null)
                    {
                        nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
                        windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate(
                            new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                            error => { }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
            }
        }
    }

    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

**My OnAppearing Method on page requiring landscape:**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            DependencyService.Get <InterfaceOrientationService>().SetLandscape();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to change the page has been changed in iOS16, you can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve it, refer to the following code:

Create an interface in Forms:

```
public interface InterfaceOrientationService    {        
void SetLandscape();        
void SetPortrait();    
}
```

iOS Project:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsOne;
using XamarinFormsOne.iOS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS))]   
namespace XamarinFormsOne.iOS    
{
    public class InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS: InterfaceOrientationService 
    {
        public InterfaceOrientationServiceiOS() { }

        public void SetLandscape() {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))    
            {    
                var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);

                if (windowScene != null)    
                {    
                    var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;   
                    if (nav != null)  
                    {
                   nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();   
                        windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate( 
                            new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                            error => { }    
                        );
                    }
               }
            }
            else
            {
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
            }
        }
            public void SetPortrait() {
    
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))
                {
                    var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);
                    if (windowScene != null)
                    {
                        var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
                        if (nav != null)
                        {
                       nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
                            windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate(
                                new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                                error => { }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Call the interface in Xamrin.Forms:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()        
{            
base.OnAppearing();            
//SetLandscape            
DependencyService.Get<InterfaceOrientationService().SetLandscape();            
//SetPortrait            
DependencyService.Get<InterfaceOrientationService>().SetPortrait();        
}
```

**UpDate**: in AppDelegate

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)        
{            
   var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;            
   if (mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last() is PageOne)            
{            
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;            
}            
return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;       
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I don't get any errors but doesn't seem to do anything. I'll load the page with rotation lock on or off the app isn't forcing the orientation called. I've edited my original post implementing your example. Are there any visible errors?

Comment: @RileyHouston I updated my answer, it works fine in ios16.